# Arduino 16-step sequencer - Notes not in sync

Tags: arduino, midi

I am using the following code for my arduino mega to send midi clock out to my drum machine & synth.
The problem appears when I also try to send midi notes exactly on the 'beat'.
Only the first note is perfectly synced, the rest of them are out of sync and you can hear it.
Is there any apparent flaw in the code?

```
// METRONOME
#include <MIDI.h>

#define LED1PIN 13
#define LED4PIN 7
#define SWITCHAPIN 5
#define SWITCHBPIN 2
MIDI_CREATE_INSTANCE(HardwareSerial, Serial1, MIDI);

void setup() {
  pinMode(LED1PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED4PIN, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(SWITCHAPIN, INPUT);
  pinMode(SWITCHBPIN, INPUT);

  digitalWrite(SWITCHAPIN, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(SWITCHBPIN, HIGH);

  MIDI.begin(MIDI_CHANNEL_OMNI);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Setting up");
}

unsigned long nextClockTime = 0;
int clockDelay = 20;
int tickCount = 0;
byte running = 0;
int pula = 0;
int currentStep = 1;
int lastPulse = 0;
int currPulse = 0;
int nextTickCount = 0;

typedef struct {
  int noteNumber;
  int velocity;
  int noteLength;
  bool enabled;
}
Step;

Step stepData[100];

void loop() {

  stepData[0].enabled = true;
  stepData[0].velocity = 127;
  stepData[0].noteNumber = 40;
  stepData[23].enabled = true;
  stepData[23].velocity = 127;
  stepData[23].noteNumber = 40;
  stepData[47].enabled = true;
  stepData[47].velocity = 127;
  stepData[47].noteNumber = 40;
  stepData[71].enabled = true;
  stepData[71].velocity = 127;
  stepData[71].noteNumber = 40;
  stepData[95].enabled = true;
  stepData[95].velocity = 127;
  stepData[95].noteNumber = 40;

  MIDI.read();
  unsigned long milliseconds = millis();
  if (milliseconds > nextClockTime) {
    if (running)
      MIDI.sendRealTime(MIDI_NAMESPACE::Clock);

    nextClockTime = milliseconds + clockDelay;
    nextTickCount = tickCount + 1;
    if (tickCount == 0) {
      if (stepData[tickCount].enabled) {
        MIDI.sendNoteOn(stepData[tickCount].noteNumber, stepData[tickCount].velocity, 1);
        Serial.print("STEP ENABLED: ");
        Serial.println(tickCount);
      }
    }
    if (tickCount == 23) {
      if (stepData[tickCount].enabled) {
        MIDI.sendNoteOn(stepData[tickCount].noteNumber, stepData[tickCount].velocity, 1);
        Serial.print("STEP ENABLED: ");
        Serial.println(tickCount);
        currPulse = millis(); //1500
        Serial.println(currPulse - lastPulse); //1500-500
        lastPulse = currPulse;
      }
    }
    if (tickCount == 47) {
      if (stepData[tickCount].enabled) {
        MIDI.sendNoteOn(stepData[tickCount].noteNumber, stepData[tickCount].velocity, 1);
        Serial.print("STEP ENABLED: ");
        Serial.println(tickCount);
        currPulse = millis();
        Serial.println(currPulse - lastPulse);
        lastPulse = currPulse;
      }
    }
    if (tickCount == 71) {
      if (stepData[tickCount].enabled) {
        MIDI.sendNoteOn(stepData[tickCount].noteNumber, stepData[tickCount].velocity, 1);
        Serial.print("STEP ENABLED: ");
        Serial.println(tickCount);
        currPulse = millis();
        Serial.println(currPulse - lastPulse);
        lastPulse = currPulse;
      }
    }
    if (tickCount == 95) {
      if (stepData[tickCount].enabled) {
        //MIDI.sendNoteOn(stepData[tickCount].noteNumber, stepData[tickCount].velocity, 1);
        Serial.print("STEP ENABLED: ");
        Serial.println(tickCount);
        currPulse = millis();
        Serial.println(currPulse - lastPulse);
        lastPulse = currPulse;
      }
      nextTickCount = 0;
    }
    tickCount = nextTickCount;
  } else if (digitalRead(SWITCHBPIN) == LOW) {
    if (running) {
      MIDI.sendRealTime(MIDI_NAMESPACE::Stop);
      running = 0;
      digitalWrite(LED4PIN, LOW);
    }
  } else {
    clockDelay = analogRead(A0) / 10;
  }
  if (pula == 0) {
    if (!running) {
      MIDI.sendRealTime(MIDI_NAMESPACE::Start);
      tickCount = 0;
      running = 1;
      digitalWrite(LED4PIN, HIGH);
      pula = 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: try not sending a whole load of serial debugging at the same time as trying to run real-time code...

Answer (score 1):

The beats are not evenly spaced. 24 - 1 is 23, 48 - 24 is 24 etc.

A simple fix would be to put your first beat on 0 not 1. Instead of incrementing tickCount, set a variable nextTickCount to tickCount +1, and assign it to tickCount at the end of the `if (milliseconds > nextClockTime) {` conditional bracket.

Also, set nextTickCount to 0 when tickCount reaches 95, but don't play any note (it will be played on the 0 beat )

Comment: 16 steps sequencer = 4 beats => 24ppqn *4 = 96.
Am I missing something?

Comment: No, you're right, I was confused and thinking in powers of 2 for some reason. Nevertheless, you do need to change the handling of the last beat (see edit)

Comment: I implemented your changes same result.. this is driving me crazy.
Please see the edited code on the top.

Comment: Leave the 24 and 48 and 72 as they were. The notes should be played on 0, 24, 48 and 72. The wrap to zero should be at 95

Comment: I tried, still there is audibe out of sync. I am starting to think maybe there is an issue with the arduino timer for this sensitive operations.

Comment: "out of sync" with what? Do you have two clock sources? They will always drift apart, it's just a matter of how quickly.

Comment: What is the expected BPM? Are you setting that separately on whatever you're trying to sync with?

Comment: There is only one clock source - the arduino.
It's pushing the master clock through midi to my other instruments.
When I start a pattern on my drum machine or my synth, it's not 100% synced with the notes played from arduino.

Comment: Instead of setting `curPulse = millis();` you can just set it like `curPulse = milliseconds;` Also, edit your question to show your latest non-working code. Also try commenting out the `Serial.println` calls because they can take quite a lot of time.

Comment: i will strip down the code to the bare minimum to indicate the issue at hand tonight.